NE555 Trigger Voltage
I'm looking to use an NE555 in monostable mode, generating a pulse of defined length whenever the trigger level drops to a low state.
I was planning on powering the NE555 from the same source as my CMOS logic network, 12V.  I have been reading the datasheet and am trying to understand trigger voltage.  It says it is nominally 1/3 of the Vcc.  In a chart on page 5 of the TI manual, however, it says that max trigger voltage is just a little bit over this 1/3 value (5.6V for 15V Vcc, and 2.2V for 5V Vcc).  Is this a limitation that shall not be exceeded or else risk damage to the components?  Or is it simply spelling out the max voltage required to set the trigger to a "high" state?
My background is a BS in MechE, and I haven't worked in the field since graduating.  I'll try my best to research whatever is necessary to understand your answers, but please keep my level of experience in mind and try to meet me in the middle.

It's simply the voltage needed to trigger. While it nominally is 1/3 of the supply, it's always within some range of tolerance around 1/3. If it should be exactly 5V at 15V supply, it will just be within range of 4.5V to 5.6V.
Datasheet says maximum allowable input voltage for the TRIG pin is the supply voltage, so 12V on TRIG pin if VCC is 12V is fine.

Thanks for the quick answer.  So if I'm understanding, using a logic "high" output (12V) as the trigger will not cause any damage or issues?
